# Macbook Two External Monitors Flashes When Last Monitor is Plugged In

Tags: macos, mac

I think it is related to a recent Mac OS update on my Macbook Pro (16 inch 2019) running 10.15.6.

I always run two external monitors. They're Dell monitors I'm running on VGA via the USB-C dongles. If I plug one monitor in, it works fine. But if I plug the other monitor in, and it doesn't matter which one I choose, all of the monitors flash from black to a screen.

I did all of the troubleshooting Apple suggested, clear NVRAM and SMC.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to unplug all of the devices from the Macbook, including the power. Power down the laptop, power it up again with none of the devices or power plugged in, and once it's back up, plug everything back in.

This process must cause the ports to re-acquire those devices and cleared whatever goofiness got in there.

Comment: Update on this, while it works to do this, for me it started doing the flashing thing again after the macbook went to sleep.